# Active Record Where Year of Date Field Greater Than Equal Current Year

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `rails 5.0` and `ruby 2.6.4`

How do I use active record to get all records where the year part of a date-field is >= the current year?  In my model `ClassSection`, users can create records that have a `start_date (date column)` field set to a future date.

This is wrong I know, but should give you the idea of what I need.

`ClassSection.where('year(start_date) >= ?', Date.today.year)`

I'm doing this in a helper method (and console to test), so not sure if a scope is needed or will work.  I was just doing this inline.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

stumbled across this:  `ClassSection.where("DATE_PART('year', start_date) >= ?", Date.today.year)`